# Disk Space is rapidly deplenishing

Tags: ssd, disk-usage

My disk space is rapidly getting eaten up and I don't know why.

I was using localhost and it was taking a long time to load so I checked the properties in the folder and I had 2GB left out of 125GB on my SSD.

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please open a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run `df -h`. That will clarify what volumes you have and how much total, free, and used space is on *each*. This is a reasonable first step toward figuring out exactly where (and what kinds of files) the disk space increase is happening. That should make it possible to determine what diagnostic step(s) to do next, or maybe even lead directly to a solution. After running that command, please select all the text in the Terminal, do Edit > Copy, *edit* your question, paste it in, and format it as "code" by selecting it and pressing Ctrl+K. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is like asking "Why it doesnt work" without giving any further information.

I guess that this might be caused by log files left out without clearing for long. If the SSD is your primary disk check the size of the /var/log folder.

Also run `sudo apt-get autoclean` it will clear out any unnecessary packages

Comment: it is 120GB 
Should I delete the contents?
I don't know how it would have gotten so big in just short time, installed Ubuntu yesterday :S

--I already ran autoclean

Comment: @Billy_2lgit_2qt using dash open the log file viewer and check if theres anything spamming there.

Comment: I found lots of spam from the apache2 error.log /var/log/apache2

Comment: @Billy_2lgit_2qt The contents of that folder are quite important but wht you can delete are the rotated log files aka the .gz files

Comment: I have an error log file 120GB in size :L

Comment: @Billy_2lgit_2qt use a text editing program to clear it out if its a inuse log file... and hope that the file editor doesnt crash :P

Comment: The files in `/var/log/` are not that important, you can remove them if you want. Removing logs that are still in use is worse, but the rotated `*.gz` files can be removed without problems.